# What is @selector directive in terms a C# developer can comprehend?

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is the purpose of using a [selector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html) here?

`CADisplayLink* displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(render:)];`

[Source:](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1) Code from a beginner OpenGL es 2.0 site

I read the definition

> The @selector() directive lets you refer to the compiled selector,
>   rather than to the full method name.

Unfortunetly, this does not clear it up for me.  My expertise is in C#.  So I appreciate it if you can relate the answer to how a similar solution might be achieved in C#.

Comment: You need to read the documentation for the Objective-C language. This is a beginner question.

Comment: Good that you found the documentation. Read the first sentence of the very page you linked again: "In Objective-C, selector has two meanings. It can be used to refer simply to the name of a method when it’s used in a source-code message to an object. It also, though, refers to the unique identifier that replaces the name when the source code is compiled."

Comment: What "similar solution" are you talking about, or rather, what's the problem you're trying to solve? Selectors and message passing -- as opposed to the method calls of other OOP languages -- are core features of the ObjC runtime and may not have a counterpart in C# (note that I don't know a lick of C#).

Comment: [iOS Objective C Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html).

Comment: @Richard: OP provided a link to that exact same chapter in the body of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A selector declares the name of a function. That's it. It's very similar to the Reflection class [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx), but it's much simpler to use.

Comparison of C# and Objective-C:
Notice the C# code may be a bit off, as I haven't worked with it in a long time

```
// C#
using namespace system.reflection;

class someClass {
     void someMethod(object input) {
           string methodName = "doSomething";

           input.getType().getMethod(methodName).invoke(input, new Object[] { });
     }
}

// OBJC
@implementation someClass 

-(void) someMethod:(id) input
{
     SEL methodName = @selector(doSomething);

     [input performSelector:methodName];
}

@end
```

As far as the internals of a `SEL` are concerned, it is a `C-string` that has been put into a private map for speed in lookup at runtime.

Comment: Actually, `MethodInfo` would be similar to `Method`, a low-level Objective-C runtime type. `SEL` has no direct equivalent.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan are you stalking me? And true, but for the sake of explaining `SEL`s, I think the comparison is fine.

Comment: No, I think we just have some of the same tags marked as favourites.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two links that together explain them pretty well. The first is Apple's documentation on selectors and the second is about the difference between selectors, delegates, and blocks (which are comparatively new).

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html

http://bradcupit.tumblr.com/post/3431169229/ios-blocks-vs-selectors-and-delegates

EDIT:

Oh, and not C#, but if you are familiar with javaScript or the like, selectors are similar to callbacks. Again, that second post helps explain the uses/similarities/differences.

Comment: The link to the docs was already provided _by the OP_ in the body of the question. Further, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The second link is the kind of information I am looking for.  Yes, I know JavaScript.  That helps too.  Thanks for taking the time to read and comprehend the question!